# Charlier-Sobolev-type orthogonal polynomials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, orthogonal-polynomials

I am currently reading an article, and I am a bit stuck on understanding a sentence in this article. The sentence, as indicated in the image, is: *" In the case of Charlier polynomials, the measure is **the Poisson distribution of probability**."*

[image]

Then they defined the Poisson distribution as $\frac{e^{−\mu}\mu^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}$. But what I know is that the distribution is $\frac{e^{−\mu}\mu^x}{x!}$ . Is what I said correct?
Thank you in advance for your help and explanations!

Comment: Those definitions are equivalent, as $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$. (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.)